# how can we fetch details of particular row from mysql database using variable in python

Tags: python, mysql

How can we fetch details of particular row from mysql database using variable in python?

I want to print the details of particular row using variable from my database and I think I should use something like this:

```
data = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM loginproject.Pro WHERE Username = '%s';"% rob)
```

But this is showing only the index value, not the data. Please help me out.

Comment: what kind of information you require to fetch?

Answer (score 0):

after executing the query using cur.execute(query), you need to call fetchall function for getting data from cursor e.g.:

```
data = cur.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM loginproject.Pro WHERE Username = '%s';"% rob)
result = cur.fetchall()
for row in result:
  print(row[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/prosaigon/Python-Connector-Mysql

python3.6
library: pip install mysqlclient

Answer (score 0):

use `cursor.fetchall` and `cursor.description` is your case

**cursor.fetchall():**

> This will provide you all the rows fetched in a tuple format.

**cursor.description:**

> This will provide you the list of columns in the query

And the one will go like :

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM loginproject.Pro WHERE Username = '%s';"% rob)
descriptor = cur.description
result = cur.fetchall()
```